# Spark read file with multiple record type

Tags: apache-spark, text, apache-spark-sql

All,

I am trying to read the file with multiple record types in spark, but have no clue how to do it..
Can someone point out, if there is a way to do it? or some existing packages?

the example below - where we have a text file with 2 separate ( it could be more than 2 )
record type :
00X - record_ind | First name| Last name
00Y - record_ind | Account #| STATE | country

```
input.txt
------------

    00X|Atun|Varma
    00Y|0002355|IL|USA
    00X|Diya|Reddy
    00Y|0002345|FL|USA
    
    sample output :
    output.txt
    ------------
    1|ATUL|VARMA|002355|USA
    2|Diya|Reddy|0002345|USA
```

Comment: Is there no key? If not, how do I know which `Y` record to join to which `X` row? Should each row be joined to the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that the `Y` record belongs to the `X` record preceding it, and that the order is guaranteed in the file, you could proceed as follows.

1. Read the text file while adding a line number value as you do so:

Note: I'm reading a string here, you could modify it for your file.

```
val inputText = """00X|Atun|Varma
    00Y|0002355|IL|USA
    00X|Diya|Reddy
    00Y|0002345|FL|USA"""

val input = inputText.split("\n").zipWithIndex.map{case (line, i) => s"$i | ${line.trim}"}.mkString("\n")

print(input)

0 | 00X|Atun|Varma
1 | 00Y|0002355|IL|USA
2 | 00X|Diya|Reddy
3 | 00Y|0002345|FL|USA
```

I can now read this text into a Data Frame as follows.

Note: I'm adding explicit column names. You don't have to and could rely on the ones generated by Spark since they are meaningless thus far.

```
val df = spark.read
  .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
  .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(("line_num|record_ind|first|second|third\n"+input).split("\n")).toDS)


df.show
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

+--------+----------+-------+------+-----+
|line_num|record_ind|  first|second|third|
+--------+----------+-------+------+-----+
|       0|       00X|   Atun| Varma| null|
|       1|       00Y|0002355|    IL|  USA|
|       2|       00X|   Diya| Reddy| null|
|       3|       00Y|0002345|    FL|  USA|
+--------+----------+-------+------+-----+
```

Finally, you can join each row on its preceding row as follows:

```
spark.sql("""select x.first first_name, x.second last_name, y.first, y.second State, y.third Country
             from df x
              inner join df y
               on x.record_ind = '00X'
                and y.record_ind = '00Y'
                and y.line_num = x.line_num +1""").show

+----------+---------+-------+-----+-------+
|first_name|last_name|  first|State|Country|
+----------+---------+-------+-----+-------+
|      Atun|    Varma|0002355|   IL|    USA|
|      Diya|    Reddy|0002345|   FL|    USA|
+----------+---------+-------+-----+-------+
```

If there could be an arbitrary number of rows connected, the record_ind would have to follow a pattern in order to determine the depth of the self-joins required.